# issue with print struct tm in c

Tags: c, struct

Suppose I have two valid time_t variables (called time1,time2) with *different* dates.

I create:

```
struct tm *time1_info = localtime(&time1); 
struct tm *time2_info = localtime(&time2);
```

When I try to print the months of the time1 and time2 variables like this:

```
printf("Time1 month %i and time2 month %i\n", time1_info->tm_mon, time2_info->tm_mon);
```

It gives me the `time2` month value as `time1`, but I know for sure they are different from each other. For example, if `time1`'s month is 4 and `time2`'s month is 7, it prints:

```
Time1 month 7 and time2 month 7
```

Why is it doing this?

Comment: How are you initializing `time1` and `time2`?

Comment: Are the times in the same month?

Comment: Test it by printing all the values, `tm_year`, `tm_mon` and `tm_day`.

Comment: Use `struct tm time1_info = *localtime(&time1);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `localtime` function returns a pointer to a static object, and calling it again may overwrite the data and then return the same pointer. If you check the value of the two returned pointers, you'll probably see that they point to the same place.

You should take the data you need from the returned pointer before calling `localtime` again:

```
struct tm *time_info = localtime(&time1);
month1 = time_info->tm_mon;
time_info = localtime(&time2);
month2 = time_info->tm_mon;
```

Some systems have a `localtime_r` function that lets you specify where to store the data instead of always using the same storage, but this is not a standard C function. The C11 standard adds an optionally supported function `localtime_s` which does the same.